# Getting parameters of one view in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am completely new to RoR. I have a parameter in one view of a controller now how can i get it in another view of the same controller?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the relevant controller code and indicate what parameters you want in both actions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I approve you to read the [ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Read the getting started chapter and then create the blog application you will see
that gives you a great entrace to ruby on rails.
Try to understand the Rails way.

Comment: The question isn't at all clear so I'm not sure how referring the poster to the homepage for the Rails Guides will help. It's also against practice here to just link to an external site as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a form or a link_to in form-a and make a HTTP (POST/GET) to form-b. Remember that you can put also any HTML (or JS) in your view that you like.

Have a look at:

[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```
link_to "Profile", :controller => "profiles", :action => "show", :id => @profile
# => <a href="/profiles/show/1">Profile</a>
```

If you want to link to a associated table you can easy do this with:

```
# @person.company.name is the name of the link
# company_path(@person.company) is the  associated model
<%= link_to @person.company.name, company_path(@person.company) %>
```